# SSH Public Key Authentication Strength Port 22

Tags: ssh, openssh

Let’s say I have a server with Port 22 opened to the internet , password authentication disabled, and root remote login disabled. Only Key Authentication is enabled. If the key is tightly secured, is there anything to be concerned about as far somebody being able to crack the key or anything like that. Apologies if the question is vague.

Comment: Yes - zero-day vulnerabilities in sshd.